# Identify remote Device Height

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a React Application and it is hosted and operated via a remote Tablet Device. I wanted to know that, is there any way I can get the Height and Width of that remote Tablet Device (Rendering Resolution)? Because, I don't have a access to that.

I need this information to design the UI to fit the device properly.